# In Eclipse there's an exclamation point next to the file folders in the packages pane. How should i fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse

This happened after I imported a project, but before that my projects were fine. It's strange because the project I imported doesn't have the exclamation point, but the projects that were already in my workspace had the exclamation point next to it after I imported a file. It says build path specifies execution environment Java-SE1.6, There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's causing the problem but try following.

You can add [Java-SE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) in your build path.

[image: BuildPath Configuration]

Check out this [tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_java_build_path.htm)